# Pivot table generating custom value by comparing the 2 column's

Tags: excel, xlsx, xls

I have below table.

```
Identity_No  Date1      Date2
     123    1/6/2018    
     456    4/7/2018    8/8/2018
     567    10/10/2018  6/12/2018
```

now i need to generate a table like below

```
Identity_No 1/6/2018    4/7/2018    8/8/2018    10/10/2018  6/12/2018
   123        y           n            n            n           n
   456        n           y            y            n           n
   567        n           n            n            y           y
```

please let me know how to create it with pivot function or any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with combination of formulas(if your data structure is as presented). If your values are in range A1:C4, please enter this formula in cell G1 and drag it to the right. You must enter this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER combination since it is an array formula.

```
=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($B$2:$D$9<>"")*(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$B$2:$D$9)=0),ROW(2:9)*100+COLUMN($B:$D),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&"")
```

This way you will extract unique dates from your range of dates in B:C columns.

[image]

then in cell f2 enter formula `=A2` and drag it to the bottom. In cell `G2` enter this formula `=IF(IFNA(MATCH(G$1,$B2:$E2,0),"n")="n","n","y")` and drag it beneath whole table.

[image]